# Hibernate+JPA+Spring Memory Leak

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memory

I am deveoloping a web application with Hibernate, JPA, Spring and Struts2. When I run the application for a few hours in my web server (VPS Tomcat) the OS send a SIGKILL to tomcat because of the memory usage. My server has 288Mb, tomcat gets killed when it reaches 200Mb aprox. Someone has told me that I need more memory but my application is small and doesn´t have too much traffic, it is not in production yet. I am using postgresql and my database is about 150Mb, it has many images. I have tried to use a memory profiler with netbeans, but the IDE becomes to slow and I have not been able to find anything.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you close properly your connections in a finally block ?

It's hard to reply without the code with only theses informations

Comment: I use Spring Framework to manage EM. EM is injected in Struts2 Actions.

Answer (score 0):

i have used JProfiler and yourkit but i am not satisfied with output for actual performance tuning and memory usage currently we have been switched to [java melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). This not only help performance optimization in dev but also in production system. Java melody is very easy to integrate and configure and in production you can enable or disable by just updating web.xml

Comment: I'll give it a try. It would be specially usefull if I can use it in production.